# Need help with list definition with content types

Tags: content-type, list-definition

I have a custom content type based on document content type, and I added some columns to this content type.

I referenced this content type from list definition like this:

```
<ContentTypes>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x010100E78B02337C812A4692E59BF81668901202">
      </ContentTypeRef>
    </ContentTypes>
```

Now when I create a list instance from this list definition, and click: new, I can't see my content type in the dropdown, I can only see New Document, I have to go to list settings and enable content types on the list, then I will see my content type in the dropdown, now if I upload any document to the library, it will not show me any columns for my content types, it will not show me the dropdown to choose my content type.

If I add this content type to other library, it will work fine, when uploading a document to the library I can choose from the properties the custom columns.

What's wrong with my process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need enable contenttype in your list def (use `EnableContentTypes` attribute of the `List`  element)
2. You need copy the field def XML section to your list def, just ref the contenttype will NOT working.

i have googled a link for you: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsnoiwb/archive/2008/12/01/creating-list-definitions-with-content-types.aspx

Comment: so I have to copy the field xml to the fieldref inside the contenttyperef, or inside the list definition itself?

Comment: inside the list def, not the contenttyperef

Comment: but why do I have to define it again? isn't the contenttyperef references the fields already?

Comment: okay... this is really 'repetitive', but you have to.   tell you some thing MS always say: `BY DESIGN`

Comment: yes seems like that!